# How do I farm creepers for XP without them exploding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have created a mob farm which I want to be able to turn into an XP farm at the switch of a button. Basically a multitude of mobs spawn at the top, fall down, and die. I want to add a dispenser that dispenses water so I can catch the mobs and kill them for the XP instead of their drops. However, creepers start to self-destruct as soon as I start hitting them through my half-slabs. I've tried using different combinations of slabs, stairs, fences, etc, but the creepers keep blowing up my mobs. Is there any way to stop this? I can draw a diagram of the XP farm if it would help.

Comment: Have you tried damaging them before, like with fall damage?

Comment: @FabianRöling you see I'm trying to convert a mob farm to an xp farm at the switch of a button so the fall without water is lethal. But this has given me an idea for an additional bubble elevator to damage the mobs for the xp farm.

Comment: creepers die from a fall height of 24 blocks, you could make the button push up a bunch of sticky pistons to raise the floor so that the creepers only fall 23 blocks and they will survive with 1 heart left, so they will die to one sword swing.

Comment: @Andrew I attempted that but the bottom blocks of the convertible mob farm are hoppers, which cant be move by sticky pistons.

Comment: Then push soul sand in from the side, hoppers still get the items through it. These are really old concepts, they are used basically every day since 2013.

Comment: @FabianRöling I was not aware of these concepts. Im new to non spawner mob grinding. If you want to make this suggestion an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You've already got some good answers, did they not help you?

Comment: @FabianRöling They did. One of them is my own, and the other is more technical (not what I was looking for). I'll just accept my own therefore (the only reason I didn't before is because I don't like doing that)

Comment: It's totally fine to do that if that's what solved your problem. It also makes it stand out to everyone who visits this question in the future.

Comment: @FabianRöling I can't accept until tomorrow. I will then. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: This falls outside of the scope of the question, but most XP farms I've seen use either The Nether or The End mobs specifically for this reason - is there a reason you prefer to use the overworld instead?

Comment: @Zibbobz No thats just where I built it. My xp farm wouldn't be compatible in the nether because of the use of water. I plan to build another one in the end though. Im new to xp farming without spawners so im learning as i go.

Comment: If you want to develop your own enderman farm and want a hint: Endermites

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes I think ill research that. Id probably better know what I'm building before I build it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have been testing this vigorously and I've found a combination of slabs and blocks and that means that the creeper cannot see you and won't explode, no matter how much it is attacked. Here it is:
[image]
Notice that the player is standing on a bottom slab, so they can peer into the whole easily.

---

Another possible solution that I found during testing is to use a combination of stairs and slabs and a bow. While this does affect the durability of the bow I think that this can be overlooked by how effective this system is.
[image]

The setup for the upside down stairs stops skeletons from shooting at you and the distance stops the creepers from exploding.

Comment: Mending on the bow could also be useful (though if you're using a general mob farm for XP, mending may not be available yet)

Answer (score 13):

First thing to note: if a Creeper is standing in water, even if they do explode, they won't blow up any *blocks*, but the explosion will still *deal damage* to you and other mobs around them.

Ranged weaponry is the best bet for killing creepers, as they need to be within 3 blocks of the player to trigger an explosion. If you stand outside of this range and shoot them, then they will not explode.

If a Creeper [cannot see you](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hitboxes#Line_of_Sight) (turn on [hitboxes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hitboxes#Hitboxes) to see their line of sight), they will not explode, even when attacked.

The only other option I could suggest is to set up cats in a line, so ensure that the Creepers don't fall down the same shaft as the rest of the mobs, and set up an automatic killing area for them specifically. You'd lose a little bit of exp, but you wouldn't have to deal with them at all.

Comment: The easiest way to filter creeper (& witches) is by making them "float" away, as both of those mobs swim up in water, while skeletons and zombies swim down

Answer (score 1):

So, I didn't really like the answer to this one, since I had a 3x3 killing chamber. Thus I kept experimenting and happily I found a solution that works. Unless your killing chamber is bigger of course. So the design is quite simple. Creeper on a full block, while you are on a bottomslab 2 blocks away with a full block (below) and a slab (in on top) between you and the creepers, so that you don't move into the danger zone.

This can be seen on the picture below.[image: This is my safe creeper killing design]

As a bonus I also designed a redstone contraption, that lets you turns your mobfarm into an XP farm by adding a layer of solid blocks, instead of using water. This way you can still kill the mobs in one hit. You can probably find a better design, but I'm quite proud of it anyway.

Likewise the picture is below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can make a really long building. In top of that, make it really dark so mobs can spawn. Add water in top of the building and make sure to not spill it to bottom of building, otherwise mobs will survive and they can kill you/other mobs.

Comment: That is the process i already have in place, my question was how to kill a creeper that fell down the long tube without them exploding.

Comment: This does not answer the question